# I fail review audits by approving answers which appear blank *after* I review them

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, deleted-answers

I was just given a 7-day audit ban for approving a potentially "low-quality" answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5233067

I thought that the original answer (which described why non-jailbroken iPhones don't have to worry about keyloggers) was acceptable, but my review was flagged as incorrect, resulting in a ban.

I'd like to learn what I did wrong(?), but immediately after I approved the answer, it started appearing as an *empty* answer.  It definitely wasn't empty when I approved it!

This has happened several times before.  From reading comments from others who have similar issues, it appears that the question was probably deleted as spam, or something, so I can no longer see it.  But I'm just guessing now.  I'd like to find out what I did incorrectly, if anything, or if there's a bug on the site.

---

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the original answer:

[image: A spammy answer]

Comment: They don't look blank to me and I'm pretty sure that's not the reason they were picked as audits. They do look like they spam for the key logger product though. (And with mod tools I can comfortably say deleting it is correct). It's also worth noting that even discounting the spam the rest of the answer is mostly thanking an older post.

Comment: The answer you said was "acceptable" was deleted, which is why you can't see it after you failed the audit.  It is, what I consider, a mistake in the design of the audit system.  There is [an existing feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209324/i-would-like-to-see-my-history-with-audits) on Meta.StackExchange to fix this, but no word on if/when it will actually be implemented

Comment: This is a screenshot of the answer http://i.stack.imgur.com/xTCOx.jpg

Comment: @Flexo , looking for some guidance on modding, since I didn't see it as spam *for* that product, more as a warning against jailbreaking. It basically said "it's possible if you're jailbroken.  For example, if you're jailbroken, this product could be used. So, to be safe, DON'T JAILBRAKE!"

Comment: In that case it's still not an answer, so deleting it is still the correct action to take.

Comment: @Flexo You don't see the answer as blank because you're a moderator. The answer was picked as an audit because it was deleted as spam, and that is also the reason why Bob (who doesn't have 10k rep) can't see it.

Comment: @MartinSmith you should post that image as the answer. It's a great example of how insidious spam can be.

Comment: @Bob - It does not look like spam to me since the poster only pointed out a sample product (he may well have been spamming his product, but I can't tell based on what I've seen). I think you probably should have failed the audit because it looks like a comment to another answer posted as an answer. Keep in mind I've been banned a few times myself, so I sympathize with you.